# Nodejs redirection failure after login

Tags: node.js, express, session

I'm studying login logic with nodejs, express, mongodb. But I having trouble with login success logic. My server workes fine before login. (register, login failure, etc...) But when login success, it makes 500 error while redirecting.

First of all,
I'm noob at nodejs and not good at english as well.
Execuse me for any inconvinence...

For detail, i'll post my codes.

app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var flash = require("connect-flash");
var session = require("express-session");
const MemoryStore = require("memorystore")(session);
var passport = require("./config/passport");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var app = express();

const maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 5;

// Other settings
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "MySecret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MemoryStore({ checkpeorid: maxAge }),
    cookie: { maxAge },
  })
);
app.use(flash());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Custom Middlewares
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});

// app.use("/", require("./router/index"));
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));

connectDB();

// Port setting
var port = 1234;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("server on! http://localhost:" + port);
});
```

./routes/index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const { render } = require("ejs");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("../config/passport.js");

router.get("/loginSuccess", (req, res) => {
  res.render("loginSuccess");
});
router.get("/loginFail", (req, res) => {
  res.render("loginFail");
});

router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login", {
    title: "login",
    link: "login",
    message: req.flash("signinMessage"),
  });
});
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/");
});
router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register", {
    title: "register",
    link: "register",
    message: req.flash("signupMessage"),
  });
});

// router.post(
//   "/login",
//   (req, res, next) => {
//     var errors = {};
//     var isValid = true;

//     if (!req.body.userId) {
//       isValid = false;
//       errors.userId = "id is required!";
//     }
//     if (!req.body.password) {
//       isValid = false;
//       errors.password = "Password is required!";
//     }

//     if (isValid) {
//       next();
//     } else {
//       req.flash("errors", errors);
//       res.redirect("/login");
//     }
//   },
//   passport.authenticate("local-login", {
//     successRedirect: "/loginSuccess",
//     failureRedirect: "/loginFail",
//     failureFlash: true,
//   })
// );

router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    failureRedirect: "/loginFail"
  }), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/loginSuccess");
  }
);

// router.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
//   passport.authenticate("local-login", function (err, user, info) {
//     if (err) {
//       return next(err);
//     }
//     if (!user) {
//       // return res.status(302).json({ redirectUrl: "/register" });
//       return res.redirect("/login")
//     } else {
//       req.logIn(user, function (err) {
//         if (err) {
//           return next(err);
//         }
//         //If Successful
//         // res.render("loginSuccess");
//         return res.redirect("/loginSuccess")
//       });
//     }
//   })(req, res, next);
// });

router.post("/register", function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("local-register", function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect("/register")
    } else {
      return res.redirect("/login")
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});


module.exports = router;
```

./config/passport.js

```js
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("../models/user");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

// serialize & deserialize User
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findOne({ _id: id })
    .then(function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

// local strategy
passport.use(
  "local-login",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "userId",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async (req, userId, password, done) => {
      console.log("passport's local-login: ", userId, password);
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({userId: userId,});
        if (user && user.validPassword(password)) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          req.flash("userId", userId);
          req.flash("errors", {
            login: "The userId or password is incorrect.",
          });
          console.log("userId or password is incorrect");
          return done(null, false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.use(
  "local-register",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "userId",
      passwordField: "password",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async (req, userId, password, done) => {
      console.log("passport's local-register: ", userId, password);

      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
          userId: userId,
        });
        if (user)
          done(null, false, req.flash("signupMessage", "duplicated id"));

        const newUser = new User();
        newUser.userId = userId;
        newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

        newUser
          .save()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("save");
            done(null, newUser);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });

      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  )
);

module.exports = passport;
```

i've tried below ways on ./routes/index.js

1. using successRedirect

```js
passport.authenticate("local-login", {
 successRedirect: "/loginSuccess",
 failureRedirect: "/loginFail",
 failureFlash: true,
})
```

it doesn't work...
[first way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDvRm.png)
it is the morgan logic it makes.
(1) GET localhost:1234/logic
(2) login with id 1234, pass 1234 (mongodb already has this data)
(3) 500 failure with printing mongodb user object

2. using res.redirect()

```js
router.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("local-login", function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      // return res.status(302).json({ redirectUrl: "/register" });
      return res.redirect("/login")
    } else {
      req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        //If Successful
        // res.render("loginSuccess");
        return res.redirect("/loginSuccess")
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

res.redirect() works when login failure, but it fails when login sucess.
[second way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdxXN.png)
it exactly same as first way

3. using res.render()
   changing

```js
return res.redirect("/loginSuccess")
```

in second way to

```js
es.render("loginSuccess");
```

It works well but i've learned that direct render in post is bad way

With login failure and register, i assuming that login or session is the problem.
But I can't getting any clue.
I've already made GET loginSuccess...
How can i fix the problem?